# sort list and maintain order with another list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sorting

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396914/how-to-sort-one-array-list-and-set-the-another-list-with-same-order-in-java), but in python.

I have two lists.
List `a` contains a set of numbers and List `b` contains a set of strings, with the 2 lists having corresponding indexes. For example:

```
a = [9,12,25,3,2,3,1]
b = ['jim','bob','cal','tim','pete','bill','jane']
```

`9` corresponds to `jim`, `bob` to `12`, etc.
I want to sort list `a` by value (greatest to least), but keep the original correspondence.
The new lists would be:

```
new_a = [25,12,9,3,3,2,1]
new_b = ['cal','bob','jim','tim','pete','bill','jane']
```

or something like `{new_a_item_sorted:new_b_item_corresponding}`, etc.

THIS QUESTION IS DIFFERENT BECAUSE:

- I want the original list sorted as well

Comment: `zip -> sort -> unzip`?

Comment: in one line `new_a, new_b = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(a, b), reverse=True)))`